# sql query SUM IF GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

This is my table expense:

```
id2 name exp date ...
1  Jack 2
2  Joe  3.1
3  Marian 5.8
1  Jack  2
1  Jack  4
3  Marian 3
```

I want this query: sum up all person expenses and if the expenses was more than 5 echo it.

I have a problem on if section (if more than 5). I grouped by id2 and `SUM(exp)` and works fine but I don't know how to imply IF. I wrote `SUM(IF(exp >= 5, 1, 0))` but sql error says is not correct group function.

```
S`ELECT id2, SUM(IF(exp >= 5, 1, 0)) as ex FROM expense GROUP BY id2`
```

I appreciate if you can help me with the query.
Thanks

Comment: Please fix your question.  Is the column called `exp` or `expenses`?  `id2` or `user_id`?  Sample results would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id2,name,sum(exp) from expense group by user_id having sum(exp)>5
```

Comment: `user_ID` should be `ID2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is what you want:

```
SELECT id2, SUM(exp),
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN exp > 5 THEN exp END) as ExpsGreaterThan5
FROM expense
GROUP BY id2;
```